# A question about tensoring and retaining exactness

Tags: homology-cohomology, tensor-products

This is a question from [this](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/ChenJ.pdf) document on the Universal Coefficient Theorem.

We have the following chain complex: [image]

We then tensor each module with $G$, and get the following complex:

[image]

How come exactness is still preserved, if we haven't assumed that $G$ is flat?

Answer (score 0):

In the attached paper, the $B_n$ (and $C_n$) are free Abelian groups.
Therefore each horizontal short exact sequence splits, and so remains a split
short exact sequence after tensoring with $G$.